# problem related JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

pls use this
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-6/wiki/DevGuideJavaFromJavaScript

IFI means int float int but if 
i want to use String then how can i write? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ljava/lang/String;
```

There is a similar example on that page (`bar`), and the linked [JNI spec](http://web.archive.org/web/20080612181745/java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432) provides further details.  However, the link is currently broken, so I used Internet Archive.